# react native maps marker custom image cannot change from default

Tags: react-native, google-maps-markers, react-native-maps

I've spent about 5 hours trying to get this to work with many different permutations of code, and then rebuilding. I cannot for the life of me change the default "red pointer" marker as the default marker image in react native maps.

```js
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps';

...

<MapView
    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
    style={styles.map}
    ref={ref => {this.map = ref;}}
    minZoomLevel={4}  // default => 0
    maxZoomLevel={10} // default => 20
    enableZoomControl={true}
    showsUserLocation = {true}
    showsMyLocationButton = {true}
    zoomEnabled = {true}
    initialRegion={{
        latitude: 37.600425,
        longitude: -122.385861,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
    }}
>
    <MapView.Marker
        coordinate={marker.location}
        image={require('./images/test.png')}        <------ HERE
        width={48}
        height={48}
    />
</MapView>
```

The images definitely exist in the right folder, I've tried different image formats png/gif/jpg/svg, I've tried using `{{uri:...}}` and `icon/image`, adding and removing width/height attributes. Nothing seems to work. I'm always getting the default red pointer.

Have I missed something obvious?

The project packager/compiler fails when I `require` an image that doesn't exist, or an unsupported type. It definitely can see the image, but just doesn't do anything with it. Same results on the emulator and on actual device.

**`image={require('./images/test.png')}`**

This line just does nothing, as if it's being ignored somehow.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```js
<MapView
    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
    style={styles.container}
    region={{
        latitude: this.state.latitude,
        longitude: this.state.longitude,
    }}
    >

    <Marker
      coordinate={{
        latitude: this.state.latitude,
        longitude: this.state.longitude,
      }}
      description={"This is a marker in React Natve"}
      >

      <Image source={require('./man_marker.png')} style={{height: 35, width:35 }} />

    </Marker>

</MapView>
```

Comment: This worked right away. I thought I tried a nested `image` in my 5 hour journey, but obviously not. Many thanks. Just need to "centre" it correctly now using the anchor points. Cheers!

Comment: Many, many thanks! The original docs don´t present this solution. In the docs, `image` is a marker prop.

Answer (score 7):

There are two solutions:

#### The first solution (recommended)

Resize your marker image with image editor(such as Photoshop,....) and use as `icon` in `marker`

To do this, you can make three photos of different sizes (`YOUR_MARKER.png` , `YOUR_MARKER@2x.png` , `YOUR_MARKER@3x.png`) (React Native automatically displays the appropriate item).

This is a good solution if you have a large number of markers.(You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59716960/6569224) to clarify this)

```js
<Marker
    coordinate={ ... }
    tracksViewChanges={false}
    icon={require('./YOUR_MARKER.png')}
/>
```

#### The second solution

As @shubham-raitka said you can use the `Image` inside the `marker`

```js
<Marker
    coordinate={ ... }
>
    <Image source={require('./YOUR_MARKER.png')} style={{height: 35, width:35 }} />

</Marker>
```

In this case, if your number of markers is high (about 50 or more) the map performance will be very low.Therefore, it is not recommended to use this method

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach that worked for me in a similar situation:  Use Image in place of Marker.  Pop-ups work the same as with a marker.  If you try this, Image is imported from `react-native`. The actual image is imported as:

`var dotImage = require('./pathToImage.png')`

```
<Marker
  coordinate={meter.latlng}
  title={"Parking Meter"}
  key={idx}
 >
<Image
    source={dotImage}
    style={{height: 6, width: 6}}
 />
 </Marker>
```

Comment: I saw Shubham Raitka's answer first, but this nested `image` tag was the solution for me. Many thanks

Comment: You're welcome.  It's a good question that many of us have struggled over.

Answer (score 1):

The way you give the width and height is a bit strange, please try with this way.

```
import MapView, { Marker, PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps';

const markerImg = require('./images/test.png'); // <-- create a const with the path of the image

<------
------>
<MapView
    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
    style={styles.map}
    ref={ref => {this.map = ref;}}
    minZoomLevel={4}  // default => 0
    maxZoomLevel={10} // default => 20
    enableZoomControl={true}
    showsUserLocation = {true}
    showsMyLocationButton = {true}
    zoomEnabled = {true}
    initialRegion={{
      latitude: 37.600425,
      longitude: -122.385861,
      latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
      longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
    }}
>
<Marker
    image={markerImg} // <----- add this the const with image
    onPress={() => this.setState({ marker1: !this.state.marker1 })}
    coordinate={{
        latitude: 37.600425,
        longitude: -122.385861,
    }}
    centerOffset={{ x: -18, y: -60 }}
    anchor={{ x: 0.69, y: 1 }}
/>
</Marker>
</MapView>
```

I hope it works for you, works for me!

Comment: I tried the static image object reference and that also didn't work for me. The nested `image` tag worked however from another answer

Comment: `center-offset` and `anchor` should be used for popups. Used for markers, users are left not knowing the real location of the marker.  Offset and anchor the popup from the marker.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep yet to just leave a comment, but the first solution works, I just had to add resizeMode or it cuts off the image if it's bigger.

```
<Marker
    coordinate={ ... }
>
    <Image source={require('./YOUR_MARKER.png')} style={{height: 35, width:35, resizeMode:"contain" }} />

</Marker>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Marker
   coordinate={d.driverLocation}
   title={d.driverName}
   description={d.autoNumber}
   onPress={() => console.warn(d.mobaNumbers)}
   image={require("../../../assets/bee.png")}
 >
 </Marker>
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work

```
import {Image} from 'react-native';
import MapView, {Marker} from 'react-native-maps';

        <MapView
          style={styles.mapStyle}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
          customMapStyle={mapStyle}>
          <Marker
            draggable
            coordinate={{
              latitude: 37.78825,
              longitude: -122.4324,
            }}
            onDragEnd={e => alert(JSON.stringify(e.nativeEvent.coordinate))}
            title={'Test Marker'}
            description={'This is a description of the marker'}>
            <Image
              source={require('./assests/custom_marker.png')}
              style={{height: 35, width: 35}}
            />
          </Marker>
        </MapView>
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?